# importing 3rd party library with webpack that uses jQuery and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to import a 3rd party theme/template into my `ReactJS` project which has some css and js code that I need. I was able to easily pull the styles but not the js.

Here's what my webpack plugin configuration looks like:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery",
          jquery: 'jquery'
      })
```

and here's my `index.js`:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'

import './vendor/js/custom.min.js'; << this is what doesn't work
```

As you can tell, the 3rd party resides in the `vendor` directory. When it tries to import `custom.min.js`, I get the following error:

```
Line 1:  '$' is not defined       no-undef
Line 1:  'jQuery' is not defined  no-undef
```

Please let me know if I should include any additional details.

Comment: You have installed jquery with `npm install jquery` correct?

Comment: yes i have @PhillipThomas

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include `$` and `jQuery` as a references to jQuery by importing like this:

globals.js

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

app.js

```
import './globals.js';
import 'custom.min.js';
```

This should enforce the order of importing and allow the window to have attached jQuery.

Comment: how about the later imports though? They can't be imported after writing

`window.$ = $;` and
`window.jQuery = jQuery;`

Comment: Ah, is `custom.min.js` not written in ES6? (Does it not have imports for jQuery and require them in global space?)

Comment: yes correct, it's not written in ES6. and yes to the 2nd question as well

Comment: The closest I've seen is doing this as a separate file before including the library. I'll update the answer as such.

Comment: hmm, it's still the same after I tried the `./globals.js` method. Bad import order

Comment: Hmm... With your plugin we shouldn't have to use import statements. Some libraries call for `window.$ = "jquery"` in the plugin config. Perhaps try that?